# Style changes keep reverting after restarting the program

Tags: xamarin

I'm working on a mobile app and I want to change the colors of some buttons but every time I change something, the changes revert back when the code itself didn't change.

For example, I'm trying to change the color of a button from purple to blue. So I simply changed the BackgroundColor in the ResourceDictionary:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#5E17EB"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,30,10,0"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding IsPrompt}">
            <Button Text="{Binding MessageArgs.Ok}" Clicked="OkClicked"/>
            <Button Text="{Binding MessageArgs.Cancel}" Clicked="ClosePopup"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

The change worked, so I stopped running the app, worked on other stuff, but when I come back to the same button, it went back to purple. So I tried changing it to various other colors and the changes worked and then changed it back to the color I wanted. Restarted the app, only for the changes to revert back to the original purple when the code clearly shows a different color.

I'm so confused, what's going on here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you.  And  I couldn't find the code  that you change the color of a button from purple to blue.

Comment: Delete app from device or emulator. Then Rebuild Solution.